# How can I make systemd run a python script on boot

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

i'm trying to have systemd execute a python3 script on boot and it fails saying some journal files were not opened due to permissions and I couldn't find any other solutions.
The script works fine if I manually start it with `systemctl start LoginAlert` but after enabling it to start on boot (with `systemctl enable LoginAlert`) it gives me the error message below.
I used a custom .service script for the execution of the script.

```
[Unit]
Description=Login alert system.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/LoginAlert.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
● LoginAlert.service - Login alert system.
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/LoginAlert.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-06-20 22:25:30 EDT; 2min 57s ago
    Process: 622 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/LoginAlert.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 622 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Warning: some journal files were not opened due to insufficient permissions
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The point is that the *Warning: some journal files were not opened due to insufficient permissions* is not the real problem. That just says that you are not able to see the log for that service.

If you run **sudo systemctl status your-service.service**, that message dissapears and you are able to see the log for that service.

Talking about running a python script on boot, I had the issue that it didn't execute the python script due to "permissions". That's what I thought.

In fact, as the script runs with root user (as it's executed at boot), ROOT DIDN'T HAVE THE LIBRARIES for python3 that my script needed. So instead of installing them with *pip3 install selenium* (for example), I needed to run * sudo pip3 install selenium* so root user had these libraries.

Hope that helped, regards!